# Combine sounds into one sound with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I would like to combine many wav files into one wav file. Bu, what I want to do is to specify the starting point for each wav file. I mean,

```
1.wav at 0.0, 
2.wav at 5.8, 
3.wav at 10.1
4.wav at 14.5
```

etc.

And create a new wav file like that. Since I know how long is each file duration, I am not worried if sounds will overlap. How can I achieve this?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1092291

Comment: This suggests to add gap between two sounds according to their starting times right? How to automatize this for 100 files?

Comment: You'll have to construct the command via scripting.